# Technologies and standards in a Kindle

Tags: java, networking, embedded, operating-system, kindle

I'm using the Kindle as an example of an embedded system to illustrate some points I'm making in a paper. Since I'm not an expert in all the technologies used, can those aware of them point them out.

For example:

- the GUI is programmed in embedded Java (which is probably a bad choice)
- Whispernet is used for the wireless platform

What are the libraries or underlying technologies and standards that this device uses? They can be for networking, wireless, operating the interface like the joystick, whatever.

Comment: *the GUI is programmed in embedded Java (which is probably a bad choice)* why is this a bad choice?

Comment: @matt because java is virtual machine based. But Amazon probably has its reasons.

Comment: that doesn't make it a "bad choice"

Answer (score 1):

From https://kindlepublishing.amazon.com/gp/vendor/kindlepubs/kdk/get-content?id=200436000:

### Frequently Asked Questions

#### What APIs are available to me in the KDK?

The KDK is comprised of two sets of APIs:

- Java version 1.4 Personal Basis Profile (PBP) APIs for mobile devices.
  PBP JavaDocs can be found at http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr217/.
- Kindle custom APIs which complement the PBP APIs and provide UI components, JSON and XML parsers, HTTP and HTTPS networking, secure storage, and other features. Other APIs like audio and dictionary access will be available in a future release of the KDK.
  KDK JavaDocs can be found at http://kdk-javadocs.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html.

#### I’ve already built a Java Micro Edition (J2ME) application. Can I port it to Kindle?

Yes. You should be able to modify existing Java applets and J2ME software to run on Kindle.

#### Does the KDK work with standard Java development tools?

Yes. The KDK can be used with any of the leading Java development tools such as Eclipse, IntelliJ, or NetBeans. The KDK is distributed as a single JAR file that you link to your project. The KDK developer documentation provides step-by-step instructions on setting up a development environment using Eclipse. The KDK can be used on Windows, Mac, or Linux operating systems.

#### Can I include other third-party software libraries with my active content?

Yes, as long as they are imported into the same binary archive file as your application. As the developer, you are responsible for verifying that you have all necessary rights to any third-party library included with your application.

#### How do I test active content?

You can test active content using the Kindle Simulator or by registering up to three Kindles as test devices on your developer account. We recommend that you test your application on a Kindle before submitting it to us for approval.

#### Will my Kindle active content work on the iPhone within the Kindle for iPhone software or on Kindle for PC?

At this time, the KDK enables you to build active content that runs on the Kindle 6-inch and Kindle DX 9.7-inch devices. The Kindle client applications for other platforms do not currently support Kindle active content.

#### How is active content protected?

Active content is protected using Kindle digital rights management.

Comment: This is about their SDK (called the KDK). Reading my question again, you may see how it's different.

Comment: @danke then I do not understand the question

Comment: Your answer is not incorrect. It just focuses on the SDK/KDK. My question is about all the computer science in the kindle, including the general things that are not specific to Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

The Kindle ebook format is actually the [Mobipocket](http://www.mobipocket.com/en/DownloadSoft/default.asp?Language=EN) format.

"Whispernet" is using an existing cellphone provider's CDMA network for carriage.

Comment: Whispernet uses 3G/EDGE/GPRS Coverage (whichever available) from AT&T or roaming partners of AT&T allover the world.